# Sharepoint List Item Alerts to Item creator

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to set up alerts to go to the item creator whenever the item is edited. Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Try to this site

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288540%28v=office.12%29.aspx

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/create-an-alert-or-subscribe-to-an-rss-feed-HA010215103.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Create an [Event Receiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx) that handles [ItemAdded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemadded.aspx). Use the following code to get the author of the item:

```
SPWeb web = properties.Web;
SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;
SPFieldUserValue userValue = 
    new SPFieldUserValue(web, item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Author].ToString());
SPUser user = userValue.User;
```

You can then [add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee577543.aspx) a new [SPAlert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spalert.aspx) to the user for the current item.